# how to find news about new, incoming and updated debian packages into debian's project archives

Tags: debian, command-line, package-management

I know that one can use https://ftp-master.debian.org/#dinstall but that requires having a browser and is perhaps inefficient as far as human-readability is concerned.

Is there any other way (some package or something) by which you can get news about what new is coming or which packages are being updated or something like that ? The idea is to know about new and updated packages coming into Debian archive in human-readable manner.